# Recursive parent name concatenation in mysql

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

I have two tables

**Course** with the following fields (ID, name, categoryID)
**Category** with the following fields (ID, name, parentCategoryID)

for Example

**Category**

*ID ------- name ------- parentCategoryID*

1 -------- Category1 ----- 0

2 -------- Category2 ----- 1

3 -------- Category3 ----- 2

**Course**

*ID ------- name ------- categoryID*

1 -------- Course1 ----- 1

2 -------- Course2 ----- 2

3 -------- Course3 ----- 3

I want to write select statement to get the following result

**Result**

*ID ------- name ------- category*

1 -------- Course1 ----- Category1

2 -------- Course2 ----- Category2 - Category1

3 -------- Course3 ----- Category3 - Category2 - Category1

which means I want to get all category until root category with ID 0 and concatenate them to get course category name

can anyone help me please ?

**EDIT**

```
with recursive
n as (
  select mc.id, mc.fullname , mc.shortname , mcc.name  as category, mcc.parent 
  from mdl_course mc
  join mdl_course_categories mcc on mcc.id = mc.category 
 union all
  select n.id, n.fullname, n.shortname, concat(n.category, ' - ', mcc.name) as category , mcc.parent 
  from n
  join mdl_course_categories mcc on mcc.id  = n.parent
)
select id, fullname, shortname, category from n
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0? If so, you can use [recursive CTE queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) for this type of task.

Comment: @BillKarwin I tried to understand the documentation, but it seems it make the recursive on one table but I have two different table with Inner Join

Comment: The recursive part is just for the category table, like https://dbfiddle.uk/WK-T8pdT  Then you join that cte instead of joining category

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
with recursive
n as (
  select r.id, r.name, cast(c.name as char(500)) as category, c.parent_category_id
  from course r
  join category c on c.id = r.category_id
 union all
  select n.id, n.name, concat(trim(category), ' - ', c.name), c.parent_category_id
  from n
  join category c on c.id = n.parent_category_id
)
select id, name, category from n where parent_category_id is null
```

Result:

```
 id  name     category                          
 --- -------- --------------------------------- 
 1   Course1  Category1                         
 2   Course2  Category2 - Category1             
 3   Course3  Category3 - Category2 - Category1
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xcedfEt4).

**Note**: I replaced the values `0` for nulls, since this is the most standard way of representing a lack of parent. You can still use zeroes, but you'll need to check the logic.

Comment: *`concat(category, ' - ', c.name)`* - this is optimistic... imagine that some `category.name` contains NULL (due to incorrect data, or even this can be revolved)... you may need to apply CONCAT_WS()  or COALESCE().

Comment: @Akina You are right. That could be an exercise for the OP to tackle.

Comment: @TheImpaler it does not work , please find my query in the Edit

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail You were right. See fixed query.