# with recursive in mysql does not work with me

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

I have the following database schema

Course (id, fullname, shortname, category)
Category (id, name , parent)

I want to make a select statement that concat all categories name of the course from leaf to top parent with id = 0

I have asked and some one advice me to use with recursive in mysql and he helped me with sample code to my problem and I have adjusted it to my schema

here is the code

```
with recursive
n as (
  select mc.id, mc.fullname , mc.shortname , mcc.name  as category, mcc.parent 
  from mdl_course mc
  join mdl_course_categories mcc on mcc.id = mc.category 
 union all
  select n.id, n.fullname, n.shortname, concat(n.category, ' - ', mcc.name) as category , mcc.parent 
  from n
  join mdl_course_categories mcc on mcc.id  = n.parent
)
select id, fullname, shortname, category from n
```

when I run the query it does not give error, but it only show the leaf category and did not make any recursive or contamination

can anyone help please?

**EDIT**

```
CREATE TABLE `mdl_course` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `sortorder` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `fullname` varchar(254) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `shortname` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
  )
```

and for Course Category

```
CREATE TABLE `mdl_course_categories` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `idnumber` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `descriptionformat` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `parent` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  )
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: please show (as text, not images) output of `select version();` and `show create table mdl_course;` and `show create table mdl_course_categories;`.  Also some sample data that demonstrates the problem would be helpful

Comment: doesn't look like mdl_course belongs in your cte; move that to the select and just use the recursive n to have something to look up the recursive category name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive parent name concatenation in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73615712/recursive-parent-name-concatenation-in-mysql)

Comment: @ysth this was my question too

Comment: @ysth I will update the question with what you asked for

Comment: Please add some sample data as INSERT INTO (5-7 rows per table) and show desired output for this sample data (textual, table-formatted). Of course skip columns not needed for your task and shorten long string data.